# How to transform values on a scale of 0-100 where values near 0 and 100 are more similar to one another than those in the middle of the range?

Tags: data-transformation

So I have an attribute that ranges from 0-100 (similarity of angles).

Now I need to transform the values, as I have realized that the values 0~20 and ~80-100 share the same characteristics actually. In particular 0 and 100 are exactly to be treated the same. This of course ruins any kind of regression I try to run. How can this problem be approached that there is still a continuous scale without a discrete break?

Comment: Maybe [regression for angular/circular data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109959/regression-for-angular-circular-data)

Comment: In part yes. I'm just uncertain if I need to prepare the data first to ensure values 0-360?

Comment: Or measure them in radians.  Or grads.  The point, of course, is that 0 - 360 is just an arbitrary unit of measurement (bequeathed to us by Babylonians of five millennia ago).  It doesn't affect anything about the concepts or procedures to follow.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the effect that you wanted is do the transformation $w_i = |x_i - 50|$, where $x_i$ represents the current values and $w_i$ represents the transformed values.

Comment: The problem with this is that it the arbitrary cut at 50 makes 49 and 51 highly dissimilar and that's unlikely to be the intention.

Comment: @whuber, in this case, 49 and 51 would be both transformed into 1. But, yes, I see your point. This is not the desired result.

Comment: Sorry; I misread your proposal.  What's intriguing about it is that it can be construed as a piecewise linear approximation to a multiple of a cosine wave, $25(1 + \cos(2\pi x/100)).$  Standard methods of transformation in circular statistics would use both a sine and a cosine, whence you are offering an approximation to those.